# Writting Multiple DynamoDB Items for Single Aggregation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, apache-flink

I'm using the Flink DynamoDbSink to store aggregations.

In order to optimize reads, I would like to write aggregation data across multiple partition keys.

The [setElementConverter](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/connectors/datastream/dynamodb/) method forces me to use DynamoDbWriteRequest which appears to only allow for a single item to be inserted into DynamoDB.

Is there a way to write multiple items to DynamoDB for a single aggregation (without re-writing the DynamoDBSink)?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the ElementConverter and use a [Custom ElementConverter](https://github.com/apache/flink-connector-aws/blob/main/flink-connector-dynamodb/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/connector/dynamodb/sink/examples/SinkIntoDynamoDb.java).

```
    public static class TestDynamoDbElementConverter
            implements ElementConverter<Long, DynamoDbWriteRequest> {

        private final RandomDataGenerator random = new RandomDataGenerator();

        @Override
        public DynamoDbWriteRequest apply(Long index, SinkWriter.Context context) {
            final Map<String, AttributeValue> item = new HashMap<>();
            item.put(
                    "partition_key",
                    AttributeValue.builder().s(this.random.nextHexString(5)).build());
            item.put("sort_key", AttributeValue.builder().s(this.random.nextHexString(5)).build());
            item.put("payload", AttributeValue.builder().s(String.valueOf(index)).build());

            return DynamoDbWriteRequest.builder()
                    .setType(DynamoDbWriteRequestType.PUT)
                    .setItem(item)
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A Custom ElementConverter is already required to use the DynamoDB Sink.  In this example, there is only a single item that is produced.  I would like to produce multiple items to be inserted into different partition keys.